# How to add scrollable height in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make UI like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJcpr.png
I'm using this code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let start = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 1
        let finish = (self.collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(indexPath.section))!

        for i in start..<finish {
            let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + i, inSection: indexPath.section)
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(path)
            cell?.center.y += 100
        }
```

But i have problem with height of `UICollectionView`(see here http://savepic.org/7780391.png )
How can i increase this height to let the last 2 rows move down also?

Comment: post the screenshot of your view heirarchy

Comment: also update the question with the scrollview size and your content view size

Comment: http://savepic.org/7775289.png
what should i update there?

Comment: The image you posted doesnt look like a single collection view. Are all the cell sizes equal ?